# Confidence Interval Standard Deviation Derivation from Mean (Tom Mitchell ML)

Tags: machine-learning, standard-deviation, means, confidence-interval

Recently I was going through Tom Mitchell's Machine Learning book and encountered a derivation of standard derivation from mean for a **confidence interval** problem.

**Mean** is defined as follows:
$$\overline\delta = {1\over k} \sum_{i=1}^k \delta_i$$

And **Standard deviation** is as follows:
$$\mathbf{ \sigma_{\overline\delta} } = \sqrt{{1 \over k(k-1)} \sum_{i=0}^k (\delta_i - \overline\delta)^2} $$

I cannot seem to understand why **$ \require{color}\mathbf{\colorbox{yellow}{(k-1)}}$** term is present in the Standard deviation formula. I know this is trivial, but it's bothering me a lot.

Any help with this derivation will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unbiased estimate for the variance of the distribution generating the $\delta_i$'s is
\begin{align*}
S^2 \doteq \frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k (\delta_i - \bar{\delta})^2.
\end{align*}
Since the variance of the mean (assuming iid samples) is 
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(\bar{\delta}) = \frac{1}{k^2} \text{Var}\left( \sum_{i=1}^k \delta_i\right) = \frac{1}{k^2} \sum_{i=1}^k \text{Var}(\delta_i) = \frac{k\sigma^2}{k^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{k}.
\end{align*}
Hence an unbiased estimate for the standard deviation of $\bar{\delta}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{k}}$. Plugging in the definition of $S^2$ gives
\begin{align*}
\hat{\sigma}_{\bar{\delta}} = \sqrt{\frac{S^2}{k}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{k(k-1)} \sum_{i=1}^k (\delta_i - \bar{\delta})^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Shouldn't the unbiased estimate be: $$S^2 = {1 \over k} \sum_{i=0}^k ({\delta_i - \overline \delta})^2$$

Comment: Naw. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Sample_variance